# Dynamaically adding Values from Bound Controls into New Datatable Row

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datatable

I'm still pretty green when it comes to vb.net and programming in general, so I apologize ahead of time if this is general knowledge.

Scenario, I am dynamically creating the control's bindings, filling a datatable with my SQL tables Schema. At this point I want to be able to fill in my form and have those values populate my datatable.

So far my solution is to add a new datarow and then assign values to each field. This seems a little redundant because I already have the fields bound. Is there a trick to filling a datatable with values from a bound control?

What I am doing for binding:

```
boundSource.DataSource = myDataSet
boundSource.DataMember = myDataTablesName
me.ClientNumber.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text",boundSource, "Client_Number")
...
```

The above works fine when I populate the datatable form SQL, but when I am trying to add a new record I have to add the various control.values/text to the datatable.

I am using a sqlDataadapter with a commandbuilder to generate the Insert, Update and Delete. I believe the relevant code is:

```
            Me.ValidateChildren()
            bounndSource.EndEdit()
            curCon.Open()
            daClientMaster.Update(ds, "CLIENT_MASTER")
            dt.AcceptChanges()
```

I would assume if I have 4 controls of varying types (text, date, etc.) and they are bound to specific fields in a datatable, that when I start the application I am starting on a new row of the datatable. So when I enter the information into the controls and then use the dataadapter update for said datatable, it would know to Insert. and really this is where the problem may lie. I am in way over my head, with too many task to accomplish, I have no time to fully understand anything I am doing (or maybe that's just programming in general.) If I am lacking an understanding of Databinding, or anything else, guidance to the correct information would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
PC

Comment: You should be using a SQL DataAdapter to get the data from the database.  You should also use a SQL command builder which takes a Select query command and generates three additional commands : Insert, Update, Delete.  You can then use the Update() method to automatically take you r DataSet and put changes back into the database.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Again I apologize about my inability to communicate my issue effectively. I am editing my post to include that information as well.